# Angular 2.1 - recreating component while routing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Angular 2.1.0, router 3.1.0.

While creating dashboard component I noticed that each time I route to it - it is created from scratch. Then I checked Tour of Heros demo plunker - same behavior.

Modifications of `DashboardComponent`

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {
    console.log('DashboardComponent constructor')
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
    console.log('DashboardComponent ngOnInit')
  }
}
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zipRdBNjrRI6HyNFvsjK). Open developer console. Run the plunker - should see 2 logs: `DashboardComponent constructor` and `DashboardComponent ngOnInit`. Click on `Heroes` and back on `Dashboard` - again 2 logs: constructing and calling `ngOnInit`.

Plunker may use old libraries. I've cloned TOH from [John Papa git](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes) (at the time of writing he uses same versions of Angular and router) and changed `DashboardComponent` to have those console logs. Result - the same.

I've added `ngOnDestroy` to `DashboardComponent` and it is called while leaving dashboard. So it looks like by design behavior. What are benefits? How can I reuse already created components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**>= 2.3.0-rc.0**

A custom `RouteReuseStrategy` can be implemented to control when routed components are destroyed and recreated or reused.

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouteReuseStrategy-class.html
- https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7757

**original**

This is "as designed". The component is destroyed when navigating away from a route and re-created when navigating back to the route.

The component is only kept if only route parameters change but the route stays the same.

There were discussions about some custom caching strategy but AFAIK nothing was done yet in this direction.

Comment: Is there a way (by adding a switch to route for example) to prevent this destroy/create behavior?

Comment: No, currently there is no way to configure that. The only way I see is to create a custom router-outlet and care about when components should be re-created yourself. I think the better way is to move state out to a service provided by the parent component and update the re-created component from this status on creation.

Comment: The benefits is that Angular2 code is simpler. The router would need to know when it can release the component. You might never navigate back to that route, so what should it keep the component for?

Comment: Agree. But developer knows that the given page will be called more often than the other.

Comment: As mentioned, they are aware of the requirement and they'll probably do something about it eventually. It's easy enough to work around though, with a service (as mentioned). There are only few cases where the DOM is built by external non-Angular2 libraries and recreation is expensive where it really hurts.

Comment: I updated my answer.